# C#, Is it possible to have an if statement in a get{ } property

Tags: c#

How do I go about the returning a boolean from a get{} property?

In the code below, I'm trying to have an if statement inside a get{} function. _apple and _orange are in separate classes.

It keeps on showing and Error:CS0161 not all code paths return a value.

```
        private Boolean _success = true;

        public Boolean Success
        {
            get
            {
                if(_apple.Success == true && _orange.Success == true)
                {
                    return _success;
                }
            //return _success; doesn't make a difference
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what do you want to return if your condition isn't met? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your problem is not specific to `get{ }`. Every method having a return type other than `void` requires the control flow to hit a `return` statement somewhere or to throw an exception (which also returns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly possible, you have just forgotten one thing.

As it is a `get` then it **MUST** return something in every case.  At the moment, you only return when the `IF` statement is true.  So you also need to add a default return value.

```
public Boolean Success
{
    get
    {
        if(_apple.Success == true && _orange.Success == true)
        {
            return _success;
        }
        return false;  //or whatever suits your case
    }
}
```

Maybe in your case you should use a nullable Boolean instead.  Then you can return null instead

```
public Boolean? Success
{
    get
    {
        if(_apple.Success == true && _orange.Success == true)
        {
            return _success;
        }
        return null; 
    }
}
```

Of course, your calling code then needs to handle a null, which may or may not be better for you!

Comment: Why not simply `return (_apple.Success && _orange.Success);` (for the first solution) if no setter for `_success` is there?

Comment: @Filburt There are always multiple ways in which you can solve a problem.  Here, I have kept the OPs code and shown what the problem is and how to fix it without refactoring it.

Comment: I'd reason that the OP slapped in the private member `_success` only to make it work somehow. Nothing wrong with your answer ... just gently steer newbies away from this slippery slope of adding stuff until things somehow seem to work which it usually doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

So what happen if your in if sth is not true.
Your get method wont return a value.

```
private Boolean _success = true;

    public Boolean Success
    {
        get
        {
            if(_apple.Success == true && _orange.Success == true)
            {
                return _success;
            }
        return false;
        }
    }
```

Like the error message says not all code paths return a value.